# How to check the valid of the PostgreSQL datetime format string taken from user?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 and PHP 7.x.

I want to check the validity of the PostgreSQL date time format received from the user.
I looked at [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html) document.

I tried that

```
<?php
$format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(), '" . $format . "') AS DATETIME");

if($query->execute()) {
    echo 'valid';
else 
    echo 'invalid';

//Result valid;

<?php 
$format = 'abcdefg';
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(), '" . $format . "') AS DATETIME");

if($query->execute()) {
    echo 'valid';
else 
    echo 'invalid';
//Result valid
```

It didn't work as I wanted.

Because query works regardless if the format is valid or not.

Example

```
//sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATETIME;
//query executed
//Result 
2018-11-16

//sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'abcdefg') AS DATETIME;
//query executed
    //Result 
    aad6efg
```

My question is how to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because it **is** a valid format.

You should probably define what you consider a valid format and perhaps compose a regular expression for that.

By the way, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, which is particularly dangerous since you are trying to verify unreliable data here.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm going to look at ways to use regular expression. By the way, this isn't my main code. I've written to test my way to mind.